# Azure API Manager POST Request/Response Limit 65,535

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-api-management

I have an Application API wrapped in API Manager on Azure cloud service.  For whatever reason when I send in a JSON payload of 1000 records or more (which translates to around 200k chars) the request is dropped.  No trace, no logging just dropped but if I truncate the payload everything works as expected.  If I send the same 1000 record payload into the underlying service (not through API Manager) all works as expected.  Is there a request or return size limit when using APIM?

Comment: Do you have any policies in APIM that process request body? Technically APIM does not have any limitations on request/response size when no payload processing is performed.

Comment: I do not think so.  I can confer with the developer that built the policy but as far as I can tell it's just processing the secret for authentication.

Comment: It would be good to ensure that there is no payload processing in policy. Can you post it here? Removing all possible secrets from it, of course.

Comment: Added a snipit of the policy.  I had to redact most of it as it was secret processing.  There is nothing processing the payload in the policy.  Also, I know for sure the underlying service works fine as when I go after it it can return the entire payload very efficiently.  This has to be an APIM issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My underlying service was matching inner response codes and applying to overall return code if they were the same.  My inner codes were all 404 "item not found".  Azure API manager treats a 404 as an error and drops large payloads.  This is per their support.  On a small return payload it will return a code of 404 and the message but on a large payload it is dropped.  Reason I was trying to return 404 is because each record in the return payload contains a status.  If the status is mixed return 207 for mixed status but if they are all the same - 200 for found and 404 for not found the overall service was returning the internal status as the overall status.  This was bad design. My payload consisted of a search for items that did not exist in the DB and therefore was returning 404 as overall status with messages for each record indicating "Not found".  APIM was dropping the return response in favor of a generic 404 url not found response.  Switched the internal service to return only 200 or 207 depending on outcome and all is right.

```
{
    "ProcessId": "2",
    "Code": 404,
    "Message": "Could not resolve token.",
    "Token": "@!!!@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }, 
{
    "ProcessId": "2",
    "Code": 404,
    "Message": "Could not resolve token.",
    "Token": "@!!!@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
```

Overall return code was set to 404 and APIM dropped the response.  I fixed this by setting overall return code to 200 in this case.